# Having issue with selecting drop down in selenium webriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a sample HTML source of the dropdown.
I have tried with all possibilities but I having

> "Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not
>   interactable" error in selenium web driver.

Plz, give me a solution to select the dropdown values in the web driver. What should I use?[HTML source  here][1]

```
WebElement clickclientdrpdown=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/form/div[1]/span/span[1]/span/span[1]")); 
clickclientdrpdown.click(); 
WebElement selectclientdrpdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/form/div[1]/span/span[1]/span/span[1]")); 
selectclientdrpdown.sendKeys("1 Private solution");
```

Comment: Please post your sample code as text, not as a link. And if you are trying to get the element via the `Selenium` method switch to using the `JavascriptExecutor` - (https://www.guru99.com/execute-javascript-selenium-webdriver.html) The `JavascriptExecutor` is not limited by the element being enabled or not.

Comment: sample code :   WebElement clickclientdrpdown=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/form/div[1]/span/span[1]/span/span[1]"));
clickclientdrpdown.click();

WebElement selectclientdrpdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/form/div[1]/span/span[1]/span/span[1]"));
selectclientdrpdown.sendKeys("1 Private solution");

Comment: I have check with Select. now showing "Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "span"" .                                                                                               Select selectclientdrpdown=new Select (driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/form/div[1]/span/span[1]/span/span[1]")));
selectclientdrpdown.selectByIndex(4);

Comment: I edited the question for you. Can you add example HTML of the element you are trying to get?

Comment: Yes, your xpath is grabbing a `span` element so that is why you get an exception. You need to get a `select` element. `By.xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/form/div[1]/span/span[1]/span/span[1]"`

Comment: how to get Select element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `xpath` is prone to breaking easily if the format of the HTML ever changes, just use `findElement(By.Name)`, the `name` attribute is less likely to change as it is part of the Form and `name` is the parameter name passed to the server:

```
//Selenium method  specific, prone to failure if element is disabled or not visible
WebElement selectclientdrpdown = driver.findElement(By.name("companyId"));
selectclientdrpdown.sendKeys("1 Private solution");



//Using the JavascriptExecutor
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("document.querySelector("select[name='companyId'].value = '1 Private solution';");
```

Comment: I tried..but showing  -----  Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable

Comment: @RupeshKatekar As I said before, `Selenium` methods will fail if the elements are not enabled or if they are not in view, use the `JavascriptExecutor`, I'll add to my answer to show you how to do it via that option.

Comment: Its working now...   WebElement selectclientdrpdown = driver.findElement(By.name("companyId"));
selectclientdrpdown.sendKeys("1 Private solution");                                      ...............we have to select the dropdown first...so i have selected it with xpath